# Can I add an attribute to a list in python?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7

Former js dev here. I am writing a program (for school)
and I need a list filled with turtle objects. However, I need to add an attribute "speed" to the list.

I know in javascript, it would be something like:

```
let a = [];
a.speed = 5
```

And then I would make a factory function for turtles using that speed attribute. I tried this in python:

```
turtles = [Turtle()]
turtles.speed = 10
```

And it threw the error: 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'speed' on line 9'

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to subclass `list`. Classes are much more common in Python than in JS, though like JS you can choose to write in (almost) any paradigm you want to. Here's a simple example, though you could get fancier.

```
class MyList(list):
    def __new__(self, *args):
        return super(MyList, self).__new__(self, args)

    def __init__(self, *args):
        list.__init__(self, args)


foo = MyList(1, 2, 3)
foo.speed = 5
print(foo)
print(foo.speed)
```

(Apologies for the truncated initial reply, I was in the middle of typing and my keyboard stopped working.)

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have Object like Javascript. Instead, it has Dictionary. to create a Dictionary in your case:

```py
turtles = {}
turtles["speed"] = 10

print(turtles)
# access turtle's speed 
print(turtles["speed"])
```